# problems with updating multiple columns in postgresql 9.3

Tags: postgresql

I want to update three columns in the profile table based on the phone table. it did not work and got error message:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "home_phone"
LINE 2:                       set home_phone = (select number from p..
```

the sample of phone table:

```
_id phone.type  phone.number
51b20fac6ddbfdb704000034    Office  403-244-1895
57b6204d7065a6a5550fe30b    Mobile  123-4567
57b6204d7065a6a5550fe30b    Home    765-4321
57e99f88b948da6c3be04366    Mobile  250-851-1041
51b20fac6ddbfdb704000007    Home    555-555-5555
```

the script:

```
update profiles f set office_phone = (select number from phone_tmp p where p._id = f._userid and type ='Office'),
                      set home_phone = (select number from phone_tmp p where p._id = f._userid and type ='home'),
                      set mobile =(select number from phone_tmp p where p._id = f._userid and type ='mobile') ;
```

the value of_id in the phone table is same as _userid in the profiles table.
I appreciate any help. thanks.

Comment: please post the error u received

Comment: I just noticed you are using alias some places and not using it at other. I will suggest u use them consistently throughout

Comment: it is  syntax error at or near "home_phone"

Comment: ok Mariuzs has already posted the answer. you are using set at multiple places

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to first create a statement which converts the rows to columns and then use that as the source of the update statement:

```
update profiles f 
  set office_phone = t.office_phone, 
      home_phone = t.home_phone,
      mobile = t.mobile
from (
  select _id, 
         max(case when type = 'Office' then number end) as office_phone, 
         max(case when type = 'Home' then number end) as home_phone,
         max(case when type = 'Mobile' then number end) as mobile
   from phone_tmp
   group by _id
) t 
where t._id = f.userid;
```

Online example: http://rextester.com/WUA44201

Comment: in your example, 2 rows have values 'Home   ' (with some spaces) so they haven't been found. If he is sure all rows that should be affected have values equal to 'Home' it will work excelent, but if not, he can change " type = 'Home' " for " type LIKE '%Home%' " but of course it will cause less effiency of query.
http://rextester.com/ZYA51395

Comment: Ok, I see you fixed this while i was writing previous comment :)

Comment: It worked. @a_horse_with_no_name, it just changed the where clause from where t.useid=f.userid to where t._id=f.userid. thanks for your solving the problem and giving me example.why did you use max?  Thanks

Comment: thanks, @Mariusz Szurgot, I am going to try your solution again.

Answer (score 3):

As error said - syntax of query is wrong.
Try this:

```
update profiles f set office_phone = (select number from phone_tmp p where p._id = f._userid and type ='Office'),
                   home_phone = (select number from phone_tmp p where p._id = f._userid and type ='home'),
                   mobile =(select number from phone_tmp p where p._id = f._userid and type ='mobile');
```

You should use only one SET keyword and separate particular assignments with comma.

Comment: I wasn't investigating semantic of query, just syntax causing error.
I'm not sure it will do the job as you want it to do, just found the syntax problem.

Comment: sorry. @Mariusz Szurgot, you are right. it did not show any error, but there are not value in the three columns. maybe type should be lower case. thanks

Comment: To be completly sure conditions like " type = 'Home' " will work correctly and effiency doesn't matter you can use conditions like this:
    " LOWER(type) LIKE LOWER('%mobile%') "